# System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient deletes some of my html and css tags

Tags: c#, html, .net, email, smtpclient

I wanna send a mail which formatted as html. I can do that but the mail comes wrong. When I open the source of the mail i saw that some of my styles and tags are removed but i do not know why. For example;

This is I want to send:

```
<div class="root-container">
    <div class="section">
        ...
    </div>
<div>
```

This is I received:

```
<div class="section">
    ...
</div>
```

This is my css style:

```
div.root-container {
        padding: 1rem;
        position: relative;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #13a455, #0a5ca4);
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

This is received style:

```
.ROOT-CONTAINER {
    padding: 1rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #13a455, #0a5ca4);
 }
```

C# Code:

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(accountContract.FromAdress, accountContract.FromName);
mail.Subject = messageContract.Subject ?? "";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body = messageContract.Body;

using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    try
    {
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountContract.MailUser, accountContract.MailPassword);
        smtp.Host = accountContract.Server;
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (SmtpException ex)
    {
        WriteLog(messageContract.MessageId, "SmtpClient", null, ex.ToString());
        return MailStatus.UnProcessed;
     }                   
}
```

I am trouble with that problem for days. I would be really appreciated it if you could help me.

Comment: Can you put your complete code. C# too

Comment: Edited the code.

Comment: Are you *sure* that SmtpClient is modifying your HTML? Are you sure it's not whatever email client you're using? Use a tool like [Papercut](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut) to intercept the raw email and inspect it.

Comment: I am not sure. Yes, html was modified but i don't know where and why. Thanks, I will try **Papercut.**

Comment: `SmtpClient` does not mess with your html, usually this is web clients that cause this. I know Gmail strips out some css and html.

Comment: My email client is Outlook 2016 desktop application.

Answer (score 2):

Email HTML readers require a mixture of inline styles and, in some clients, HTML-based style markup.

HTML just requires everything to be included inside the  (no  tag, no scripts, and no external resources.). In other words for example you have to use inline styles of css instead of referencing them .

Comment: First, All your styling need to be done Inline. No external resource (CSS, Script) reference works in HTML Mail. 

So your `root-container` will be like :

    <div class="root-container" style="padding: 1rem;position: relative;background: linear-gradient(to right, #13a455, #0a5ca4);">
        <div class="section">
            ...
        </div>
    <div>

Also, you should check out the support for HTML5 in Mail. Not every thing works as intended. This resource has a lot of info.
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/transforms/backface-visibility/